# Javascript reload not working if www missing

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have javascript code that refreshes a page every few seconds and it works fine in Chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 dev-m with or without www in the URL.

But with Firefox and IE 11, it only works with www.mysite.com but not when I load mysite.com.

I have both www and (not www bindings for the site in IE.
I can't find anything on the web about this problem with Javascript reload.

Here's the function:

```
function Refresh()
    {
        window.location.reload( false );
    }
```

You'd think it would use whatever URL is in the browser, wouldn't you?
How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the developer console for errors?

Comment: I found the error finally;huge file and one type. Thanks Pointy.